# Iframe Video Not working after one time play in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

This is my iframe code and video url is coming from cloudinary where our all videos are uploaded.

```
    <iframe
      title="background-video"
      src='https://res.cloudinary.com/vfcteam8/video/upload/v1657785901/vfc-assets/c695bf51-2e60-4107-9e57-9002beb9e68d/b5283ba7-884c-4bb5-b523-d88ae58fe0c5-Snow_5.mp4.mp4'
      frameBorder="0"
      allowFullScreen
      allow={`${autoplay && 'autoplay;'} encrypted-media`}
    />
```

I have tried with loop attribute and also done research but only for you tube videos solution is there , what is for other videos url..?

If anyone knows Please share your thoughts on this.
Thank you in advance:).

Comment: src seems to be a hard-coded value, you don't need to wrap it in `{}` wrap it in quotes.

Comment: I know that ie. not issue :(.

Comment: I tried using just HTML and it works fine, can you inspect DOM and check what happens to it after playing it once.

Comment: My video length is 30 sec so after 30 sec it is stopped and blank screen occurs.

Comment: Can you still see iframe in DOM ?